# Facing issue with React-hook forms

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-hook-form

I copied/paste the first example of the React Hook Forms from NB 3.0 and getting this error. *TypeError: errors is not an Object*. (evaluating '"firstName" in errors'). Any idea why?

Comment: Provide more details and code snippets so your question can be clear and easily understood

Answer (score 6):

The example provided here [Native Base V3 React-Hook_forms](https://docs.nativebase.io/react-hook-forms) does not use the controller correctly to get onChangeText state and to catch errors for the value, to fix this change the following;

1. Change the line: `const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();` to `const { control, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();`
2. In the Controller change  `render={({ onChange, onBlur, value })` to `render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } })`
3. In the Input component change `onChangeText={(val) => onChange(val)}` to `onChangeText={onChange}`

Reference is from the integration example on the React-Hook-Form website here: [React Hook Form with React Native](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#ReactNative)